# how do I install vuforia in unity(5.4)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

How do it create AR maker(vuforia/unity(5.4))?

I installed vuforia in unity.
when I check the AR maker about vuforia, in some of Articles about Vuforia, there is "data set load behavior" on inspector.

However, I can't find the "data set load behavior" on inspector.

what should I do to list the "data set load behavior" on inspector?

I have already added App License key at Vuforia Behavior.

But I can't find "data set load behavior" in Vuforia>Prefabs>ARCamera(inspector).

[image]

please tell me how to create "data set load behavior" at inspector on ARcamera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.First create target images in Vuforia website's Target Manager create a database(this depends on what kind of target you are looking for). If it's a normal image, then select device (for first practice) and then select and upload it to the website.

2.After it's uploaded, Download the database to your PC which will be downloaded as an "Unity Custom PAckage".

3.Open Unity project. Assets - Import Package - Custom Package. Select the package that you just downloaded from the vuforia website.

4.Select ARCamera , in the inspector menu ,Check the load object target on detection- Activate the database(Name that u provided in vuforia website).

That's it.